# Asp.Net inline coding

Tags: asp.net

```
<% 
   int i = Eval("NAME").ToString().IndexOf("."); 
   string str = Eval("NAME").ToString().Substring(i + 1); 
%>
<img src="../images/img_<%= str %>.gif" alt="" />
```

EVAL("test.txt")

I need "txt" how to make ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building the entire string on the server side

```
<img src=<%= "../images/img_" + str + ".gif" %> alt="" />
```

Comment: @bwarner ı need inline coding, not server side how to make { string str = eval("name") } ?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand your question then.  Could you edit the question and add some more details on the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try Split function

`Eval("NAME").ToString().Split('.')[1]`